# Не работает mouseleave после mouseenter на SVG USE символе

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg

Мне нужно чтобы при mouseenter символ в SVG менялся с #dot на #dot2.
И при mouseleave - наоборот.

Mouseenter работает, после этого другие события (mouseleave, onclick) не срабатывают.

[ссылка на JSFiedle](https://jsfiddle.net/dmitry335/9mwfu4y7/2/)

```js
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.point', function() {
  this.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", '#dot2');
});
$('body').on('mouseleave', '.point', function() {
  this.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", '#dot');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>

  <svg width="260" height="140">
    <defs>
        <symbol id="dot2">
            <circle fill="#444D5D" stroke="#1F232E"  cx="15" cy="15" r="11.7"/>
            <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#1F232E"  d="M22.8,6.3c-2.1-1.9-4.8-3-7.8-3s-5.7,1.1-7.8,3L15,15L22.8,6.3z"/>
            <circle fill="#FFC72C" stroke="#1F232E"  cx="15" cy="15" r="4.5"/>
        </symbol>

        <symbol id="dot">
         <circle fill="#444D5D" stroke="#1F232E" cx="15" cy="15" r="7.5"/>
            <circle fill="#FFC72C" stroke="#1F232E" cx="15" cy="15" r="3.6"/>
        </symbol>
    </defs>

    <use xlink:href="#dot" x="50" y="20" class="point"/>
    <use xlink:href="#dot" x="80" y="20" class="point"/>
</svg>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Задайте свг id и вешайте события не на body, а на свг.
Например:

```
$('#svg_id').on('mouseenter', '.point', function() {
  this.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", '#dot2');
});
$('#svg_id').on('mouseleave', '.point', function() {
  this.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", '#dot');
});
```

Ну и хтмл:

```html
<svg width="260" height="140" id="svg_id"></svg>
```